# All of a sudden module complains datetime() -missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)

Tags: python, datetime

I have a function that gets files and paths then puts them in a dict. It was working fine until this week. Suddenly it started giving this error.

```
TypeError: function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)
```

That error refers to `d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))`. What is wrong and how can I fix?

```py
def get_newest(filepath: str) -> dict:
    maxs = {}
    for file in Path(filepath).iterdir():
        if file.is_file():
            *_, t, d, _ = file.stem.split('_')
            d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))
            maxs[t] = file if t not in maxs else max(file, maxs[t])
    return maxs
```

Comment: Has the naming convention of your files changed in the last week?

Comment: No, sir. I checked before posting and just doublechecked now. The function unpacks from  the back which is date separated by `-` and then `_` time. Thank you for your time. I will break the function out and test on it's own and see if I can start working through it like that. Thanks again.

Comment: So it would break for example if it encountered a filename like `foo_bar_2023_baz.csv`, because the portion before the `_` then only contains one number, which isn't enough for the datetime constructor to work.  The fact that it complains about a missing "month" (the second arg) indicates that it's only getting one arg.

Comment: Basically, the filename needs to contain at least two underscores, and when you split it by underscore, the penultimate portion has to be a `-`-separated date.

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig into what you've said. Thanks again!

Comment: @slothrop A file got put in one of my folders that didn't belong. Thanks. The error was confusing. Appreciate it.